# What are the default values of clientOptions for mongo-go-driver?

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go

I was trying to search for default values for clientOptions for mongo-go-driver.

I am trying to initiate new client in following way:

```golang
        opts := options.ClientOptions{}
    opts.ApplyURI(connectionURI)
    sharedConnection, err = mongo.NewClient(&opts)
```

I was wondering what will be the default values for few of the clientOptions like ConnectTimeout, MaxPoolSize, MaxConnIdleTime.

```golang
   type ClientOptions struct {
    ConnectTimeout         *time.Duration
    Compressors            []string
    Dialer                 ContextDialer
    HeartbeatInterval      *time.Duration
    LocalThreshold         *time.Duration
    MaxConnIdleTime        *time.Duration
    MaxPoolSize            *uint16
    Monitor                *event.CommandMonitor
    ReadConcern            *readconcern.ReadConcern
    ReadPreference         *readpref.ReadPref
    Registry               *bsoncodec.Registry
    RetryWrites            *bool
    ServerSelectionTimeout *time.Duration
    Direct                 *bool
    SocketTimeout          *time.Duration
    TLSConfig              *tls.Config
    WriteConcern           *writeconcern.WriteConcern
    ZlibLevel              *int
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

The following default is based on `mongo-go-driver` v1.1.x and MongoDB server v4.2. You can also find out more information/behaviour on [MongoDB driver specs](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/tree/master/source).

```
ConnectTimeout         30 * time.Second
Compressors            nil (compression will not be used)
Dialer                 net.Dialer with a 300 second keepalive time
HeartbeatInterval      10 * time.Second
LocalThreshold         15 * time.Millisecond
MaxConnIdleTime        nil (no limit)
MaxPoolSize            100
Monitor                nil
ReadConcern            nil (server default `local`)
ReadPreference         readpref.Primary()
Registry               bson.DefaultRegistry
RetryWrites            true
ServerSelectionTimeout 30 * time.Second
Direct                 false
SocketTimeout          nil (infinite)
TLSConfig              nil
WriteConcern           nil (server default `w:1`)
ZlibLevel              6 (if zlib compression enabled)
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is not flow to set the default value then it will set to Zero Value. Zero Value is when a variable is declared, and not explicitly initialized, it will be allocated storage with a default value

1. ConnectTimeout --> time.Duration, data type default value = 0s b.
2. MaxPoolSize --> uint16, data type default value = 0
3. MaxConnIdleTime --> time.Duration, data type default value = 0s

another :

1. bool --> default value is false
2. string --> default value is ""
3. int ---> default value is 0

Comment: I don't think that by default maxPoolSize will be set to 0.